# Is this a bug in gmpy2 or am I mad?

Tags: python, math, gmp

I'm trying to use the gcdext function in gmpy2 but I always get the result (0,0,1) regardless of what I put as the arguments. I expect it's a bug, but just to check, should this result in (0,0,1) or not?

```
from gmpy2 import *
print(gcdext(13, 21)) #Should be (1,-8,5)?
```

Comment: Seems that your source code is OK, And works well.

Comment: What result does it give you? I get (0,0,1) but I think the result should be (1,-8,5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in converting from Python long to the internal mpz type. As a quick work-around, convert the arguments to mpz first.

BTW, I'm the maintainer of gmpy2. Can you open an issue at http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/ ?

Update: This bug is fixed in gmpy2 2.0.0b2.

Comment: I would but I'm one of the few people it seems without a Google account. Thanks for the work around, it works.